# Server api key: migration doc vs migration video

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The only change that the [GCM -> FCM migration doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update-server-endpoints) *requires* is changing the endpoint:

> Update your server code to use new FCM endpoints for sending messages via HTTP and XMPP... ***Optionally***, you may want to evaluate the FCM HTTP v1 API, which offers an improved security model and new capabilities for customizing messages across

But the [video](https://youtu.be/IeexEiFprY8?t=440) seems to tell a different story:

> I'll ***need*** to update to a new more secure server key which I can get from the firebase console... download the service account credentials then I'll drag the JSON file into my project... replace the GCM API key with this service account key I'll update my HTTP header to use this access token...

Can we continue to use the GCM server api key when sending requests to the new FCM endpoint or do we "need to update to a more secure server key" obtained from the FCM console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GCM documentation you pointed out is kinda (not that much) old. It shows what needs to change when migrating from GCM to FCM *Legacy*. What Jen Person showed in the video is when you are to use [FCM v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) (see the `uri` on [8:19](https://youtu.be/IeexEiFprY8?t=499)).

> *Can we continue to use the GCM server api key when sending requests to the new FCM endpoint or do we "need to update to a more secure server key" obtained from the FCM console?*

From my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53951147/4625829) (with minor updates):

> Depending on which type of GCM API Key you were using (if this is a reeeaally old project, you might still be using a different type of Key), it may not work. Regardless, after you *import* your GCM project to Firebase, it would probably generate the necessary API Keys (Server Key for this matter) that you could (and should) use in order for FCM to work.

Comment: Is this correct: If the GCM project is very old, then when importing the GCM project to Firebase, the new server key that is generated will likely be different. If the GCM project is very new, then when importing the GCM project to Firebase, the new server key that is generated will likely be the same. In both cases, the server key that FCM shows us can be used in FCM legacy API calls to push to devices with GCM-generated tokens and FCM-generated tokens?

Comment: Almost there. Regardless if the project is new or old, after importing the project to Firebase, it would generate it's own Server Key that you could use. The difference of an old and new GCM project is that recent ones probably have a *Server Key* (same type of API Key that FCM uses) which should *probably* still work for FCM.

Comment: "_Server Key_ which should _probably_ still work for FCM". Assuming we're in the case where the Server Key would still work, is it possible to make FCM legacy api calls with that key *without importing the GCM project to Firebase*? Or is it only possible to send requests to `fcm.googleapis.com` with a key associated with an official Firebase project?

Comment: Based from my previous experience (note that this was way before when the advise to migrate was just recent), the Server key still works even if you don't import the project. With all that said, I would still strongly suggest that you import it as suggested.

Comment: AL., I would appreciate your insight on https://stackoverflow.com/q/54096613/1168364 especially as it relates to our discussion here on compatibility.