# Migrating from GCM to FCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the Firebase Console once we import GCM project to FCM I saw that it creates a new API key. Will the old GCM API key also work?

Comment: Depending on which type of GCM API Key you were using (if this is a really old project, you might still be using a different type of Key), it may not work. Regardless, after you *import* your GCM project to Firebase, it would generate the necessary API Keys (Server Key for this matter) in order for FCM to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server api key: migration doc vs migration video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926285/server-api-key-migration-doc-vs-migration-video)

Answer (score -1):

just create your project on FCM and follow below link

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

and register your project and download google json file andput in your project

enjoy