# revoke GCM Server Key after migration to FCM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm planning my project's migration from [GCM to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

An experienced FCM person [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53926285/server-api-key-migration-doc-vs-migration-video#comment94889963_54020405):

> ... after importing the project to Firebase, it would generate its own Server Key that you could use [in FCM legacy API calls to push to devices with GCM-generated tokens and FCM-generated tokens]

With this new Firebase Server Key I would no longer need the old GCM Server Key. Because the old GCM key won't be necessary I'd like to revoke it to limit possible attacks. **Is it possible to revoke all old GCM Server Keys for  a project after migrating the project to FCM?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. GCM Projects were provided Server Keys that are accessible via the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) (make sure you select the correct project).

[image: 1]

From the screenshot above, you could see ***Server key (auto created by Google Service)***. The option to delete the API Key can also be seen here -- the trash icon is beside the copy icon.

If you already imported the project to Firebase, navigating to the [Cloud Messaging tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/) would also show the *old* Server Key, aka the **Legacy Server Key**.

[image: 2]

Choosing to delete the default Server API Key will show the following prompt:

> This credential will be deleted immediately and permanently. Once deleted, it can no longer be used to make API requests.
>
> Do you want to delete the credential?

Proceeding to delete the key, then refreshing both pages afterwards, would show a new auto created Server Key.