# relationship between source GCP/GCM and destination Firebase/FCM project

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on [migrating from GCM to FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

I'm trying to understand what the relationship is between the legacy GCP/GCM project and the new Firebase project. When we do the regular import as explained in step 1, the project in Firebase has the same name as the original GCP/GCM project.

We have a team that owns GCP project x and a separate team that owns GCP project y. The legacy GCM resources are part of project x. Is it possible to import the GCM resources from project x into a Firebase project that is associated with project y? (Assuming the person importing is an owner of both x and y.)

Comment: Hey @lf215. Saw your comment from your other post. Can you be more specific as to what are the *GCM resources* are? Do you mean the API keys? If you are, then I would strongly suggest that you reach out to official Google/Firebase support on this one. Currently, I don't think it's possible, but still reach out to official support.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming issue, rather a question on project property migration that is best asked via the service's official support channel.

Comment: I've reached out to support. (Let me know if you'd like me to delete.)

Comment: No worries. I've voted this for closure, but it's only my opinion for it to be closed. If other reviewers see it that way as well, then it would be closed later on. If it doesn't and you managed to get an answer from the Official Support team, you could post it as an answer here. So as to help someone in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. The Firebase project must also be in the 'y' scope to be accessed by the GCM/GCP project 'y'.

Comment: Do you have any supporting documentation or is this from experience? Can you explain the association between GCP projects and Firebase projects when importing GCP projects into Firebase?

Comment: Yes, I have experience. Firebase projects can be created in 2 ways. 

1. If you create in the Firebase console, then the GCP project created to support it will not be visible to you in the GCP console.

2. The second case is importing the project in Firebase Console. Now, a new project is not created and the GCP project created already is used. Firebase also uses the same billing account as in GCP.